# How can I print else or if statement only once when the condition is meet instead of infinite without breaking

Tags: python-3.x

In the below python code I am checking if google is up when it is up its printing "google.com is up" infinite amount of times,
I want to print just once and wait until it'll go down and when google goes down I want to print "google.com is down" just once and again when google goes up print "google.com is up" like wise continue the loop without breaking.

```
hostname = "google.com" #example
while True :
  response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + "> /dev/null")

#and then check the response...
  if response == 0:
    print (hostname, 'is up!')
  else :
    print (hostname, 'is down!')
```

Comment: You ave this in a `while true` statement so its never gonna stop.

Comment: you're currently a prisoner to your infinite loop, username checks out.

Answer (score 1):

You can add variable for checking last value. E.g. if response is 0, setting variable value and print. If response value doesn't change, not print and change variable value

Something like that:

```
hostname = "google.com" #example
state = -1
while True :
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + "> /dev/null")
    if response == 0 and state != 0:
        print(hostname, 'is up!')
        state = 0
    else:
        if state != 1:
            print (hostname, 'is down!')
            state = 1
```

Comment: its printing google.com is up and then google.com is down one after another continuously but google was up the whole time.

Comment: I fixed code. I hope it solves the problem

Comment: You may want a `time.sleep(1)` somewhere in there so you aren't flooding google with ICMP packets. They might start rate limiting you which would cause a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is True, but if you are in a loop, and want to do something only the first time it's triggered, and not subsequent times, then you would need to flag the first time vs. subsequent times.  E.g., before the while statement, initialize two variables, e.g., first.true = 1 and first.false = 1.  Inside the if statement, only print if first.true = 1, and after that (but still inside the if statement), set it to 0.  This ensures that it will only print the first time it gets there.  And likewise with first.false inside the else statement.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I came across your answer as part of a Stackoverflow review process. I just wanted to say that I find is helpful to include some code illustrating my idea when I answer a question. It will likely be better received.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a break statement to exit while loop, for example like that:

```
hostname = "google.com" #example
while True :
  response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + "> /dev/null")

#and then check the response...
  if response == 0:
    print (hostname, 'is up!')
    break
  else :
    print (hostname, 'is down!')
    break
```

However, i am not understanding your question so good, using a state variable like in the other answer should be ok too!!

Comment: i dont want to end the pythonscipt when its host is up or down. Sorry I am bad at explaining and thanks for trying to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `update` function with a static `last_update` string. The update function will not print the same output twice.

```
def update(st):
    if not hasattr(update, "last_update"):
        update.last_update = ""
    if update.last_update != st:
        print(st)
        update.last_update = st


while True:
    hostname = "www.google.com"
    response = os.system("ping " + hostname)

    # and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        update(f"{hostname} 'is up!")
    else:
        update(f"{hostname} 'is down!")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below code its continuously pinging my home server printing 'down' only onetime when its down and waiting, When the server is up printing 'up' only onetime then again when the server goes down it'll print (down) only onetime.

```
hostname = "172.16.0.96" #example


while True :
    while True :
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + "> /dev/null")
        if response != 0:
            print("down")
            break
    while True :
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname + "> /dev/null")
        if response == 0:
            print("up")
            break
```